# Sound of ⟨д⟩ in Днепр

Tags: произношение

I recently realized that the first phoneme in the word Днепр is not [d̪] at all. The position of my tongue is very much different from what it takes to pronounce [d̪], or [d] for that matter. What’s that phoneme, then?

Comment: What phoneme is it close to when you pronounce it?

Comment: my tongue is set against the upper row of the front teeth like in the standard ***Д*** but the sound itself isn't a full ***Д*** because of the following ***Н***, so they unite into one sound, kind of nasal ***Д***

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка - Keep calm and "nasal **_Д_**" is actually **_Н_** )). The first sound in _Днепр_ is just [dʲ], don't make simple things over-complicated. There are neither "nasal [d]" nor [dn͡] affricate in Russian.

Comment: I don't think there are minimal pairs, so that it is only of interest to very specialized linguists.

Comment: @Yellow Sky yeah, nah, i don't claim it to be a phoneme in its own right, just tried to describe how it's perceived on my end which may resemble the impression the OP has

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called `фаукальное д` - this happens when some specific consonants stand before `н` or `м` - to be more precise, before nasal consonants.

Here's a [quote](https://sci.house/grafika-orfografiya-fonetika-scibook/foneticheskie-yavleniya-styike-85212.html):

> Стык предлога со следующим словом фонетически почти не отличается от
>   стыка приставки и корня по образованию комбинаторных оттенков фонем,
>   например: под ним [под- н’іім] — поднять (плдн’'ат’| (фаукальное д)

More about nasal release (this is how it's called in English) one can find in a Wikipedia article:

> Фаукальный взрыв (от лат. faux/fauces, faucalis — глотка, глоточный) —
>   взрывной звук, образуемый в зеве, характерный для такого образования.
>   Возникает в положении неносового взрывного согласного перед носовым
>   того же места образования, в результате замены ртового взрыва
>   (например, б, д, п) зевным вследствие опускания нёбной занавески при
>   переходе от смычного к носовому; смычный при этом характеризуется
>   некоторой имплозивностью (сомкнутостью). Например, ро**тн**ый, го**дн**ый,
>   нэ**пм**ан, тще**тн**ый, о**бм**ан, пригод**н**ый, по**тн**ый и т. д.

Comment: as it transpires i wasn't in my observation that far from the truth